# ereg_replace removing spaces

Tags: php

I'm trying to use `ereg_replace()` to only allow Upper and lower letters and, and spaces since I will be exploding it using commas.

I have this code below but it's removing the spaces and I can figure out how to allow , to pass through.

```
$type = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z\.-:/-]", "", $string);
```

Also I know `ereg_replace()` is deprecated but this is the closes I have gotten.

Comment: Why are you using `ereg_replace()` since **`preg_replace()`** can do that?

Comment: "Also I know ereg_replace() is deprecated but this is the closes I have gotten." to work.

Comment: So the only reason why you are using ereg instead of preg is _to work_? Sorry, I don't understand...

Comment: The reason I'm using it like I said it's the closet I have gotten to get it to work. People always ask to show what you have so far so I did. If you can correct me by showing the correct code I need to use, thats would be great.

Comment: @AbbyE I already did (-:

Comment: the biggest problem with using deprecated features is that they **will** be removed from a future version of PHP. So when you upgrade (or your webhost upgrades without telling you), your code will suddenly stop working without any warning. (actually, you will have had a warning -- that's what the deprecation notice is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following

```
$new_string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z ,]/', '', $string);
```

That will allow A-Z, a-z, commas and spaces and remove everything else.

NB. Everything else includes accented characters etc.

Comment: Actually, I think this will replace `[A-Za-z ]`, with `''` or am I mistaken?

Comment: Don't you mean `[^A-Za-z ,]`? :-P

Answer (score 3):

simply escape the comma and the space

```
$type = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z\.-:/-\,\ ]", "", $string);
```

same result can be had with conversion to preg

```
$type = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z\.-:\/\,\ ]+/", "", $string);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me! Also thank you for providing me alternatives beside bickering it's deprecated as I noted to others.

Comment: note that you still have some tweaking to do, as I only replicated your existing regex and added the space and comma...  take a look at teh other contributors to get an idea how to tweak your expression if you are needing to refine it further.

Answer (score 2):

*Don't* use deprecated features, they are deprecated for a reason. If you want to allow only a-z, A-Z and spaces, use:

```
preg_replace( '~[^a-z ]~i', '', $subject );
```

*Edit*: as per your comment "it's still removing commas and spaces", I take it you want commas to be allowed as well. In that case, use:

```
preg_replace( '~[^a-z, ]~i', '', $subject );
```

Comment: Best answer so far. **Should be approved.**

Comment: Why not just use `/` to delimit the regex instead of `~`?

Comment: Matter of taste really. I use regex to match things like URL's, and I've found that when using `~`, you do a lot less escaping :)

Comment: That's handled by the `i` on the end. `i` is for `case Insensitive`

Comment: agreed about the `~`, although when one has to work with other languages that don't have an option of delimiters, sometimes it's just easier to use the same syntax across the board.